# fiware-servicepath' header value does not match the number of notified context responses

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I am having issues with Fiware Cygnus, i had this same issue before but i was connected to "attrsFormat": "legacy". This time that is not what is causing it.

What lead to this issue.

1. I create subscription:
   [image]
2. Subscription body
   [image]
3. Orion send notification to cygnus, then this happens.

[image]

I had no problems with Orion and Cygnus when my service path was like /example/something
But it seem issue is connected with this service path in use /.

I could also share my name_mappings.conf but i think this issues is not connected to that since it never come to point of sending data (in my case to CKAN).

So is this service path allowed and can Cygnus work with it, if not what i missed which could lead to this.

Comment: Not sure if there is something in Cygnus that precludes to work with `/` service path but I would say that the servicepath name is a key element in the processing done by Cygnus sinks (ie. it is used as token in table names in MySQL) so it is advisable using a non-default service path.

Comment: Yes i agree about servicepath as key, i used it to persist data into CKAN and had no problems until now. What make this issues strange is that Cygnus configuration if no service path is provided will used value of "/" so that tell me it should not be issues regarding this. I know for sure that it is not connected to name mappings because in Cygnus schema Http rest handle come before even mappings are used. Thankf for replay as allways.